# How to get distributions of LinearThompsonagent in tf_Agents

Tags: tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, tf-agent

I am working on contextual bandits in tf_Agents and using the linearUCB agent and leanr thompson sampling agent.

I can get the actions, but not sure how to get the distributions (over actions) out of the agents for a given timestep.

I know linearUCB is deterministic and hence no distribution, but couldn't get the distribution from thompson sampling even with `linearthompsonsamplingagent.policy.distribution(timestep)`. It says distribution are deterministic and the log_probability is blank.
Can someone please explain how to get  distributions out of it.

Comment: We're also facing a similar problem using the tf-agents library for Lin-UCB. Just checking if you were able to find any workaround for this. Did any other policy help with providing a distribution?